# How to produce this kind of an effect to an image

Tags: html, css

[image]

I wanna create this kinda color for my background image.
I tried this `-webkit-filter: opacity(.5) drop-shadow(0 0 hsl(277, 64%, 61%)); filter: opacity(.5) drop-shadow(hsl(277, 64%, 61%));`, still it aint working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `before` selector add `background` color and `opacity` to overlay image

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:before {
  content:"";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: indigo;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay img {
  width: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543269865-cbf427effbad?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" />
</div>
```